# How do I modify my new user field in a Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-breeze

I'm practicing some basic Laravel skills using a Laravel Breeze app. I decided to add a new `postal_code` field to the default `User` entity, and so far, that's largely gone quite well: After editing `User.php`, editing the frontend registration form, editing my TS User type and creating a migration, I am now able to register a new user, fill out the registration form and have the `postal_code` saved in the database.

The problem comes when I try to edit my logged-in user. I update `UpdateProfileInformationForm.vue` to include my new `postal_code` field:

```
        <TextInput
            id="postal_code"
            type="text"
            class="mt-1 block w-full"
            v-model="form.postal_code"
            required
        />
```

... and I then go to http://localhost/profile to fill out the form, and when I hit `save`, I verify in the browser inspector that the postal code is being submitted as part of the sent JSON:

```
{"name":"Test User","email":"test@example.com","postal_code":"21202"}
```

However, that appears to be where things end. The form refreshes with the old postal code, and no new value is saved in the database. (The old value remains.)

Is there another place where I need to add my new field? I took a look at `App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController.php`, but I couldn't make much sense of what was going on there, as everything seemed pretty abstracted.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: if I recall correctly, there is a model mapping stating the fields (named).. so laravel knows what data goes into the database where. Also, please check if the underscore could be the cause of your issue (eg. go for camelcase naming convention once), as you named your field postal_code

Comment: Where is ProfileController found? I can't find it in the incldued breeze boilerplate

Comment: @apokryfos it is in App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController.php

Comment: Make sure you add the new field in your model's `$fillable` array (see [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment))

Comment: @apokryfos good tip. It's in there.

Comment: So if the controller in question is [this one](https://github.com/laravel/breeze/blob/1.x/stubs/default/app/Http/Controllers/ProfileController.php#L12) then it uses `ProfileUpdateRequest` as the form request to perform validation so you need to also update the validation rules in that (to whatever the field needs to be e.g. `required|string` or maybe a regex for valid postcodes)

Comment: @apokryfos aha! Yes, that makes sense. I had missed that it was using something other than a generic `Request`. I assume it's common to see custom requests in Laravel? I'll tuck that under my hat if so.

Comment: Personally I like using [form requests](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation) for either complicated forms or for requests I would like to reuse in multiple places. In the end of the day it's up to you to decide how your app will look like.